# scraping stock futures data from nse website using python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

Here is my code

```
url_oc = "https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes"
url = f"https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/derivatives?symbol=WIPRO"
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
             AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
                     'like Gecko) '
                     'Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36',
       'accept-language': 'en,gu;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8', 'accept-encoding': 
          'gzip, deflate, br'}
session = requests.Session()
request = session.get(url_oc, headers=headers, timeout=5)
cookies = dict(request.cookies)
response = session.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5, cookies=cookies).json()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtCS4.jpg)

**i am not able to get data

getting error**

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the complete example to grab data from api whatever you desired.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
data=[]

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36',}
with requests.session() as req:
    req.get('https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/derivatives?symbol=WIPRO',headers = headers)

    api_req=req.get('https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-derivative?symbol=WIPRO',headers = headers).json()
    for item in api_req['stocks']:
        data.append([
            item['metadata']['instrumentType'],
            item['metadata']['openPrice']])


cols=['instrumentType','openPrice']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
print(df)
#df.to_csv('info.csv',index = False)
```

Output:

```
     instrumentType   openPrice
0    Stock Futures     646.15
1    Stock Options      12.05
2    Stock Options      23.00
3    Stock Options      29.00
4    Stock Options      20.40
..             ...        ...
170  Stock Options       0.00
171  Stock Options       0.00
172  Stock Options       0.00
173  Stock Options       0.00
174  Stock Options       0.00

[175 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: how to extract only futures data of all expiries

Comment: @F.Hoque, Could you please let me know how can I extract the "marketLot" data ? I tried item['tradeInfo']['marketLot']. However I am getting KeyError: 'tradeInfo' error.

Comment: item["marketDeptOrderBook"]["tradeInfo"]["marketLot"] does the job for me for the query ask by me above this comment

Answer (score 1):

To get JSON data from that page use correct API URL:

```py
import json
import requests


api_url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-derivative?symbol=WIPRO"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0",
}

with requests.session() as s:
    # load cookies
    s.get(
        "https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/derivatives?symbol=WIPRO",
        headers=headers,
    )
    data = s.get(api_url, headers=headers).json()

# pretty print:
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "info": {
        "symbol": "WIPRO",
        "companyName": "Wipro Limited",
        "industry": "COMPUTERS - SOFTWARE",
        "activeSeries": [
            "EQ"
        ],
        "debtSeries": [],
        "tempSuspendedSeries": [],
        "isFNOSec": true,
        "isCASec": false,
        "isSLBSec": true,
        "isDebtSec": false,
        "isSuspended": false,
        "isETFSec": false,
        "isDelisted": false,
        "isin": "INE075A01022"
    },
    "underlyingValue": 661.95,
    "vfq": 32001,
    "fut_timestamp": "08-Oct-2021 15:30:24",
    "opt_timestamp": "08-Oct-2021 15:30:13",
    "stocks": [
        {
            "metadata": {
                "instrumentType": "Stock Futures",
                "expiryDate": "28-Oct-2021",
                "optionType": "-",
                "strikePrice": 0,
                "identifier": "FUTSTKWIPRO28-10-2021XX0.00",
                "openPrice": 646.15,
                "highPrice": 669,
                "lowPrice": 645.95,
                "closePrice": 662.25,
                "prevClose": 645.65,
                "lastPrice": 662.75,
                "change": 17.100000000000023,
                "pChange": 2.6484937659722796,
                "numberOfContractsTraded": 11655,
                "totalTurnover": 123179.36
            },

...
```

Comment: how to extract only futures data of all expiries